# About .obj 3d model format and VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo, .obj

Are the amounts of v, vn and vt same in an .obj model ? I ask it because i can only use one index per draw so i have that to use VBO

```
struct VertexCoord
{
float x,y,z,w;
float nx,ny,nz;
float u,v;
};
```

so i can use one index for all buffers by striding offsets.

Comment: Why should that matter? You should construct an VBO from the data loaded from .obj yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, the number of v, vt, vn can be different.

notice that there is a list of "v", then list of "vt", "vn", etc...

At the end there is a list of faces: 1/2/3, 4/5/4, etc.
Faces index vertex pos, texture coords, normals, but since those indexes are not related to each other this also means that num of vers can be different.

Only when the list of faces looks like "1/1/1", "4/4/4" we would have the same about of attributes.

This is a bit tricky to explain, but I hope you get the point :)

So in general you cannot directly map obj data into your VBO structure.
In OpenGL you can use indexed geometry of course, but that means one index per all attribs for particular vertex. You cannot index position, texture coords separately. You have to somehow rearrange the data.

here are some links:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Load_OBJ

http://xiangchen.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/loading-a-obj-file-in-opengl/

Comment: but i can't use different indices while drawing one VBO ? that's where i am confused at. i loaded vertices seperately, i don't know what to do after loading faces. maybe re-order them according to the face data after loading, then i won't need to use glDrawArrays because i have already ordered list. i am very confused :/